# What does actually mean by 'one-off object' or rather 'simple one-off object' in PHP especially with respect to the concept called Anonymous Classes?

Tags: php, oop, object, php-7, anonymous-class

Below is the text from **PHP Documentation** :

> Support for anonymous classes was added in PHP 7. Anonymous classes
>   are useful when simple, one-off objects need to be created.

I didn't understand the meaning of the term **'one-off object'** or rather **'simple one-off object'** from the above text.

Someone please explain me the meaning of this term in a simple, lucid and easy to understand language.

Also, please explain me how the anonymous classes are useful when **simple, one-off objects** need to be created?

Do these **'one-off objects'** or rather **'simple one-off objects'** are used in live websites and applications?

Comment: Explained very well here https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/318-PHP-7-Anonymous-Classes-Tutorial.html

Comment: @NicoHaase : The answers of question you linked are not explaining what does actually mean by 'one-off object' or rather 'simple one-off object' in PHP. So, please remove the Duplicate mark from my question. Please let someone answer who knows about this. Thank You.

Comment: @SerialKisser have a look at the definition of anonymous classes and then you'll see that "one-off objects" mean just that: instantiate an object on-the-fly without writing a usual class definition

Comment: And no, this makes this question a duplicate of other questions.

Comment: As a possible alternative to casting an arbitrary array to an object, just so that you can use object syntax to reference properties rather than array keys; you can create a "custom" object from an arbitrary array with methods (e.g. to create a read-only object)